# Installer cannot replace old version

Tags: .net, setup-project

I'm following an installer project and want to set it for upgrade, but I found that after I change the version number, etc and install in client PC, it show two programs in same name, same folder.

The program could run normally but it shown two program in same name in "Programs and Features" in Control Panel.

Due to the change is too long, may I have any hints can make new installer replace the old one?

Thanks

Comment: When you say "setup-project" what exactly are you using? Is this the old Visual Studio setup project, WiX, something else?

Comment: Visual Studio setup project

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you did this correctly:

[Updates to Setup Projects](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/updates-to-setup-projects/)

so that the UpgradeCode is the same, then the most likely explanation is that one of the installs was per machine (Everyone) and the other was per-user (Just me) or vice versa, because one cannot upgrade the other. One way this can happen is if one install was by an admin and the other was not because VS will fall back to per-user for a non-admin. Or the user chose differently between the Everyone and Just me choices in that dialog. If you were to log on to that machine with a different user account and one of the entries disappears in Programs&Features that will be the explanation.